# frida read file from android device report error

Tags: android, frida

I would like to use frida 16.2.1 read a file from android13 device. I try below code but it reports the following error:

```
[*] [type]: error

[*] [description]: Error: expected an unsigned integer
```

```
   var String = Java.use("java.lang.String")
    var Files = Java.use("java.nio.file.Files")
    var Paths = Java.use("java.nio.file.Paths")
    var URI = Java.use("java.net.URI")
    
    var path = Paths.get(URI.create("file://" + pathName))
    var fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(path) // crash at this line
    var content = String.$new(fileBytes)
    return content
             
}
```

The crashed line is using a Path object, not sure why frida report expect unsigned int.

Comment: Your code works for me using an absolute path to a file within the app private app directory. What path do you use? How large is the file you want to read?

Comment: @Robert Good findings, my case is reading other process's cmdline, something like: /proc/<pid>/cmdline, it will repport error. Maybe due to hooked api do not have permission to access that file?

Comment: Yes, apps can not query other apps processes. That was introduced AFAIR in Android 12 or 13.